# Wolfram Language remove vertices

Tags: image, graph, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I have generated graph image in Wolfram Language using `CompleteGraph` function (and `Image` function, of course). How do I remove vertices from the image, so that only edges are visible. Setting `VertexSize` to 0 didn't help, because the edges don't go all the way to vertices, but they end near the vertex.
My current code is:

```
graph := CompleteGraph[4, VertexSize -> {0,0}, ImageSize -> 500]
img := Image[graph]
```

But that makes the vertices look ugly.
How do I make the vertices disappear?

Comment: If you look at FullForm[ Show[ CompleteGraph[ 4, VertexSize->{ 0,0 }, ImageSize->500] ] ] you see the top part of that is Line[ bunch of endpoints of line segments ] where each line segment is one of your edges. Note that the line segments do not meet up. Could you imagine extracting that Line[ .. ] and writing a little code to tweak those endpoints so they meet and then rebuilding and displaying the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VertexShapeFunction` and `EdgeShapeFunction`

```
    graph := CompleteGraph[4, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", ImageSize -> 500]
```